# One Plus Nord N10 5g Does not always save the Photo taken by Camera Intent using Media Store URI

Tags: android, mediastore, android-contentresolver

I am developing an app that takes a photo using the Default camera app of phones utilizing the Camera Intent to take picture. I am creating the URI to be passed on the camera intent via Media Store here is a snippet

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val imageCollection =
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    "$randomName.jpg"
                )
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                put(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/$folderName"
                )
            }

            try {
                context.contentResolver.insert(
                    imageCollection,
                    contentValues
                )
                    ?.also { uri ->
                        return@withContext uri
                    }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                return@withContext null
            }
        }
```

Sometimes it works but most of the time it does not save the photo. When it does not save the photo the intent result is Activity.RESULT_OK.

This only happens in Oneplus Nord N10 5g

Comment: Android versions of used devices?

Comment: the device is running android 11

Comment: `This only happens in Oneplus Nord N10 5g` Now please reread my first question and answer all.

Comment: I have tested it on other android 8 to 11 devices and it worked just fine. By the way I have a different way to generate the URI on android 8 to 9 that uses File API no Media store

Comment: You are not using IS_PENDING twice.

Comment: Oh I see can you help me provide an example? I think you have a good point

Comment: Google a bit for an example. There are plenty. Or read stackoverflow pages tagged `mediastore`.

Comment: I tried to add IS_PENDING on the content values and set to true when finished and still the same

Comment: You should first set to 1. And at update to 0. You could show your code.

Comment: sorry but does not work

Comment: Well then sorry too. I dont know and have no idea.

Comment: Try to write to that uri yourself instead of using a Camera app.

Comment: I think its a bug of the Oneplus camera app its working when I use Open Camera to pass the activity to capture the photo

Comment: Indeed one should always try different camera apps. Good point.